# Renaming an uploaded document based on required fields

Tags: document-library

I have a document library where people upload several reports a week when they are uploading them I have several required fields that tell what report it is. But I often find that people don't name the filename of the report correctly.

So we end up with several files just being named something like January Report

Is it possible to force the file name and title to be based on the required fields?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do a directly "calculated" value for it, however with a custom workflow it should be simple.

Try hiding the "Title" field from the upload screen so the users can't fill it out, then have a workflow edit the field to whatever string you want. You'll have to set the workflow to run when items are added to the list and (optionally) whenever the item is updated.

The change via workflow may not change right away, but after a refresh it should show...

---

An alternative to this is making a new "Title" field which is just a calculated column, which can create a new name based on filled fields. I wouldn't recommend this, however, as the search function on SharePoint runs a query on titles. If the default Title field not filled in, makes documents harder to find.

Comment: I have read about people saying MS flows is the way to do it but I have yet to find an explanation of how to do it I have tried to use flows with the option available but it doesn’t work :/ I may just have to wait for our Sharepoint Admin to make it

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea, however we might as well get used to the fact that mandatory fields are not enforced by Microsoft anymore, and I would therefor recommend looking into some kind of workflow that validates the file name compared to the metadata whenever the metadata is changed